Handling direct value updates?
Got everything working just fine so far.  However, I want to be able to retrieve values from my map and use their set methods to update the values directly.  Unlike other java maps this does not work with ChronicleMap and I can understand why. Looks like I need to issue a fresh put() or computeIfPresent() or something like that everytime I want to update my values. This isn't going to be a flyer for me though.
Any other ways to handle this?  Some kind of listener, for example?  Use of advanced options within the BytesWriter/Reader serializer I wrote.
Sorry I didn't make this clear.
Here's a much cut-down schematic of my situation...
public class MyClass{
    private SomeState state;
    public MyClass(){
        state = new SomeState(/* some params for initial value */)
    }
        
    public SomeState getState(){return state;}
        
    public void setState(SomeState state){/* sets state */}
}

class TestClass{

    @Test
    public void test(){
        
        try(Map<Integer, MyClass> map = ChronicleMap
                .of(Integer.class, MyClass.class)
                .valueMarshaller(/* my marshaller */)
                .averageValue(/* average value */)
                .entries(/* number of entries */)
                .create()){

            // Create ChronicleMap entry
            MyClass a = new MyClass();
            map.put(0, a);

            // Modify state of the value retrieved from the map 
            SomeState modified = new SomeState(/* some params */);
            map.get(0).setState(modified);

            // Test fails - guessing because I should have done...
            //
            // MyClass c = map.get(0);
            // c.setState(modified);
            // map.put(0,c);
            //
            assertEquals(modified, map.get(0).getState());
        }

    }
}

So I can't retrieve a value from the ChronicleMap and update its properties directly without issuing a fresh put() - or at least in my code it does not work. Probably because the map's off-heap. A conventional Java map in memory would allow this of course.
Am I right about this?  Any way around it?
Many thanks..

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please [edit] your question to include the documentation link of the ChronicleMap class you are using and change the provided source code to include the import statements you have. Also include the remaining source code of .valueMarshaller(/* my marshaller */), see [mcve].

Maybe you meant something like getUsing? - I am not really familiar with the class.

The values and keys in a ChronicleMap instances are serialized when stored in the "off-heap". This means they exists only there as a byte sequence. "Getting" the data back results in deserializing the byte sequence to an object. Please [edit] your question on why you use a ChronicleMap with such feature when you don't want to edit the returned objects directly and expect them to be updated in the ChronicleMap instance.

Hi Progman - I'm evaluating ChronicleMap for my purposes.  My interest is in creating a very large map in the first instance that can subsequently be used to store updated values arising from multiple stages of calculation.  I don't want to call put() everytime I update a Value, though.  This will be a big performance overhead.

Thanks Joop - will take a look at this.

Probably misunderstood the fundamentals of off-heap storage being new to it.  The need to serialise each time I update a value in my map is probably inescapable.  So back to the drawing board for me in some shape or form now. Thanks.
